# Asp.Net Sending PDF to browser

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, download, pdf-generation

I've been trying to get this aspx page to serve up a pdf.  It works correctly in Firefox, but IE gives

> Internet Explorer cannot download getform.aspx from SERVER_NAME
>   Internet Explorer was not able to open this Internet site.  The requested site is either unavailable or cannot be found.

This is the general functionality of my code.  It's spread across multiple functions (this is why we're not using WriteFile - sometimes we generate the pdf on the fly), but this is generally it:

```
FileStream fs = File.Open(Path.Combine(PdfBasePath, "form.pdf"), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
Stream output = Response.OutputStream;

byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
int read_count = fs.Read(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
while (read_count > 0)
{
    output.Write(buffer, 0, read_count);
    read_count = fs.Read(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
}

fs.Close();

Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf;
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=form.pdf");
Response.Output.Flush();
Response.End();
```

Looking at Fiddler, the page is being fetched using this:

> GET /getform.aspx?Failure=Y&r=someencryptedstring HTTP/1.1

It is being returned to the browser thus:

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>   Date: Thu, 09 Apr 2009 22:08:33 GMT
>   Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
>   X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
>   X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
>   Pragma: no-cache
>   Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=form.pdf
>   Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
>   Pragma: no-cache
>   Expires: -1
>   Content-Type: application/pdf
>   Content-Length: 628548

This is really bugging me.  I'm not using SSL, otherwise [this KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=KB;EN-US;q316431&) would seem to apply.  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried connecting from multiple clients and maybe different versions of IE?

Comment: Yeah.  We have two servers up for testing: my local, and a production-scale server.  I've tested with IE6, IE7, Firefox, and Safari.  All work just dandy except the IEs.  Those just freak out.  This is the same from other machines as well.

Comment: Let me add that it doesn't matter if the pdf shows up inside the browser window, or if the browser opts to just download it to the users HD.  Either is fine.  But IE does neither.

Comment: For others who might be running into this same problem who ARE using SSL, see here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038707/cant-display-pdf-from-https-in-ie-8-on-64-bit-vista/1140875#1140875

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the Content-Length being returned in the header actually correct for the file you're sending?  I'm just comparing this to some production code we use here and it looks like we explicitly set the Content-Length header.  If I recall correctly, some browsers have a problem if the header and the actual file size don't match.

**Edit**
The question author found that changing the Content-Disposition header to application/download instead of application/pdf seems to work around the problem.

Comment: Yeah, they match.  Windows Explorer reports the file size to be 613 KB (628,548 bytes), or 616 KB (630,784 bytes) on the disk.

Comment: I assume it's failing the same for both the file-based and generated pdfs, right?  Is it possible to conditionally use Response.TransmitFile() for the file-based ones and see if that fixes anything?

Comment: I think it's the URL.  I moved the code to a page without an encrypted string on the URL, and it worked ok.  It looks like IE is ignoring the content-disposition header and using the name of the page, including query string, as the name of the file.

Comment: Your comments moved me in the right direction - IE is ignoring the content-disposition tag.  A google search led me to the solution - changing the content-type header to "application/download" appears to fix the problem.  I'm marking your answer as correct.  Thanks for the boost.

Comment: Yeah, the only other thing that I found different between your code and my code is that inside the Content-Disposition header, we don't have a space between "attachment;" and "filename=blah".  IE might just be barfing on the space.  We do use application/pdf for our pdf files though.