# PDF in iframe flipped 90 degrees

Tags: javascript, css, pdf, web-applications, safari

I'm working on an AJAX generated page with a PDF iframe. It works fine on all the Windows browsers, when testing on Mac OSX's Safari, I noticed the PDF in the iframe was flipped 90 degrees. The page orientation in the file is landscape.

The code for the iframe is basic:

`<iframe id="myFrame" src="/some/pdf/on/the/server/doc.pdf" width="100%" height="400px" frameborder="0">`

When inspecting the iframe, I saw no compromising style properties in the `<embed>` tag (where the actual PDF lies), other than width, height and inline display. Also, when opening the PDF in a new tab, it displays correctly.

I'm using Safari 6.0.4

Has this happened to anyone before? A fix or a pointer to a fix will be highly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

The same problem was experienced by somebody [here](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?259407-Safari-rotating-PDF-iframes).

Any idea about what the PDF should contain to make Preview happy?

Comment: I found a similar question like this here ->> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12974115/to-open-pdf-file-in-iframe