# Open pdf file in IE without downloading prompt

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

While using `window.opener.top.location.href = downloadURL` in my javascript it give download option in IE9. I want it to open PDF in browser it self. It is working fine in Chrome.

Comment: I think you have to set mime type in the servlet response, so IE can know how to handle it.

Comment: try this link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12974315/475125

Comment: You need a `content-type: application/pdf` and `content-disposition: inline` to be sent by the server with the PDF file. Use F12 or Firebug to see what the server is sending. Also, user (or their IT dept) can configure IE to always download. You cannot control this.

Comment: This may be a setting that the user gets control over, not you. Check the first paragraph in http://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/display-pdf-browser-acrobat-xi.html