# Displaying PDF file in the object tag

Tags: html, knockout.js, durandal

I need to display pdf file in my SPA application built using Durandal framework. I'm leveraging "attr" knockout data-binding to provide the url of this pdf file at run-time.

```
<object data-bind="attr: { data: DocumentUrl() }" type="application/pdf" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"></object>
```

The emitted html displays the tag correctly,

```
<object data="http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/documents/TradeOverview.pdf" type="application/pdf" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; margin-right: 0px; margin-left: 0px; display: block; opacity: 1;" data-bind="attr: { data: DocumentUrl() }" data-view="durandal/../../templates/TnC/TnCDetails" data-active-view="true"></object>
```

However, the pdf file does not get displayed in the browser! 
When I run the above emitted html in sample html file, it works. Not sure why it is not getting displayed through my main app. Any pointers?

Thanks.

Comment: Hey have a look at this other stackoverflow answer about putting it in an IFrame instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12974115/to-open-pdf-file-in-iframe

Comment: Hey thanks Mark..! Just tried now and it working fine.Just out of curiosity, any known issue with <object> tag ?

Answer (score 0):

This is because browser inconsistently handle dynamic <object> tags, and often times such tags are implemented by ActiveX controls that don't listen for changes to the object tag.

2 options to pursue:

1. Use an iframe and point it to your PDF. That will cause the browser to handle PDF natively (for example, Chrome displays PDFs using its own engine, Firefox displays PDF using JavaScript library, IE uses ActiveX...).
2. Rather than data-binding the object tag, if the PDF changes, just remove the object tag and write a new one in its place. Browsers pick up changes to the DOM just fine.