# Read uploaded file in struts2

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, file-upload, struts2

How to read uploaded file in struts2?

I am developing a web app and i have some issue when i upload file : I can upload type of file i needed 
 like :  i can  upload and read image   but i can't  read others file when i upload him

here is my jsp file :

```
<s:form action="fileUpload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <s:file name="toBeUploaded" label="Choose file to upload" />
    <s:submit value="upload" align="center"/>
</s:form>
```

Action Class :

```
public class FileUploadAction extends ActionSupport implements ServletRequestAware {

    public File toBeUploaded;
    public String toBeUploadedFileName;
    public String toBeUploadedContentType;
    private HttpServletRequest servletRequest;

    public String execute() {

         String filePath =             servletRequest.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
         System.out.println("Server path:" + filePath);
         File fileToCreate = new File(filePath, this.toBeUploadedFileName);

         try {
            FileUtils.copyFile(this.toBeUploaded, fileToCreate);
            FileUtils.copyFile(toBeUploaded, fileToCreate);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            addActionError(e.getMessage());
        }
        return SUCCESS;
    } + getters/setters




<action name="fileUpload" class="com.ged.control.FileUploadAction">
<interceptor-ref name="basicStack"/>
 <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
<param name="maximumSize">9999999999</param>
<param name="allowedTypes">image/gif,image/jpeg,image/png,application/msword,
 application/mspowerpoint,text/doc,text/plain,application/pdf,application/ms-excel,application/xml,application/powerpoint,audio/mpeg3,audio/x-mpeg-3,video/mpeg,video/x-mpeg,audio/wav,application/x-mspowerpoint,application/vnd.ms-excel,video/avi</param>
            </interceptor-ref>

            <interceptor-ref name="validation"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="workflow"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"></interceptor-ref>

            <result name="success">/uploadSucceed.jsp</result>
            <result name="input">/fileUpload.jsp</result>
        </action>
```

result page :

```
<article class="module width_full">
                <header><h3>Post New section</h3></header>
                File Name : <s:property value="toBeUploadedFileName"></s:property>
                    <br/>
                Content type: <s:property value="toBeUploadedContentType" ></s:property>
                    <br/>
                User file :<s:property value="toBeUploaded"></s:property>
                    <br/>
                Uploaded file: 
                    <br/>
                    <img src="<s:property value="toBeUploadedFileName"/>" ></img>

        </article>
```

Comment: You can't do it like that (with an s:property). Use an iframe: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12974270/1654265 or something similar

Comment: I have new approach how can i insert file uploaded in  database with hibernate using this attribute  public File toBeUploaded;
    public String toBeUploadedFileName;
    public String toBeUploadedContentType;   And  change this path  servletRequest.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/"); by    my own path like C:\fileuploaded

Comment: this seems like a new question to me... btw I suggest you to use JPA2, and hibernate as JPA implementation, instead of raw hibernate...

Comment: Yah i m using Hibernate with JPA but now I have no idea for implement that :D

Comment: http://stevedaskam.wordpress.com/2011/03/28/using-jpa-to-insert-and-retrieve-blobs-and-clobs/ , http://tamanmohamed.blogspot.it/2011/05/jpa-insert-and-retrieve-clob-and-blob.html and http://www.developerscrappad.com/278/java/java-ee/ejb3-x-jpa-how-to-store-an-image-file-or-a-binary-as-blob-in-database/

Comment: When googling for this kind of things, do not put Struts2 as search tag: struts2 has nothing to do with that. Use it as front controller, but once the file is in your Action, the framework is irrelevant.

Comment: nice , I already tried this trick but it is not recommended for because i can upload video ... so database becomes heavy.  what i want  is  insert urlpath and  name of  file

Comment: What *we* want is you to write a new question, with *all* (and *only*) the basic informations related to this new question :/

Comment: Ok  i found something helpful i  will  tested before write new question look  that http://codeglobe.blogspot.com/2009/08/file-upload-struts2.html

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>
    <package name="default" extends="struts-default" namespace="/">
        <action name="fileUpload" class="com.pkg.FileUploadAction">
            <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
                <param name="maximumSize">1048576</param>
                <param name="allowedTypes">
<!--  it will allow to upload any file  image/png,image/gif,image/jpeg,image/`enter code here`jpeg -->
                 </param>
            </interceptor-ref>
            <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"></interceptor-ref>
            <result name="success">uploadSucceed.jsp</result>
            <result name="input">fileUpload.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```