# Struts2-Streaming Video From Byte Array using struts2

Tags: struts2

I am just a beginner in Struts2,
I want to display the videos,images in my JSP and I am able to get list of all images, videos from database as byte array list,when i tried  to display 1 image or video this is what happening..any suggestion..for display list of images(`<img>` tag) and video(flash player)??how to achieve this :)

(1)i tried this,result in(screen shot)

```
image=get.loadImage();    
setVideo_Content(new ByteArrayInputStream (image));
```

browser is asking me to download...the content :(

If I use this code..

```
//response.getOutputStream().write(image);    
//response.getOutputStream().flush();
```

the image is taking the whole page..cant able to display within image tag..

struts xml

```
<result name="success" type="stream">    
<param name="contentType">${yourContentType}</param>    
<param name="inputName">Video_Content</param>    
<param name="contentDisposition">attachment;filename="${yourFileName}"</param>    
<param name="bufferSize">1024</param>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This :

```
<param name="contentDisposition">attachment;filename="${yourFileName}"</param>
```

is telling it to download the file. Change it to :

```
<param name="contentDisposition">inline;filename="${yourFileName}"</param>
```

to open it inside the browser with a plugin, when available.

Also, to prevent opening it full browser, try [using an `<iframe/>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12974115/to-open-pdf-file-in-iframe/12974270#12974270) or similar, making the `src` attribute pointing to your download Action.

Comment: hey thanks LIGIOS for replying :),i changed the contentDisposition in struts xml,now its not asking me to download the content...but how should i have to call the action class in <iframe> tag i used <s:url action="getVideo"> tag in src...and browser showing error that video file might be corrupted cant play...

Comment: hi ligios,as u told i tried and its working :)for images within a frame,i set contenttype (image/jpg)
jsp:<iframe>
<img src="<s:url action='getimage'></s:url> "/></iframe> 
and for video (video/mpeg)
here is my code entityManager = JPAUtil.getEntityManager();
     CacheManager cacheManager = CacheManager.getInstance();
     byte[] vid=entityManager.find(VideoModel.class,video_Id).getVideo_Content();
            jsp:<embed src="<s:url action='getvideo'></s:url> "/>
but its neither showing error nor playing video....wat could be the problem>>>
and thanks for help :):)

Comment: It's not clear to me what is working and what is not. Please, edit your own answer instead of posting code in comments that is unreadable. P.S: are you sure your video is mpeg ?

Comment: hey ligios,every thing is working fine(video,image)it was mismatch  in video format :(,i have one clarification can we have multiple contenttype???and pass list of images,videos(List<byte[])to the page,i tried setVideo_Content(new ByteArrayInputStream(ImgList)) we cant cast List to ByteArrayInputStream....what could be the best way to achieve this...???

Comment: Call multiple actions :)

Comment: :D:D:)cool what if we have to implement in real time project,will they use the same trick...???:P :P,anyway thanks a lot Ligios