# Load Pdf file into a div using jQuery/AngularJs

Tags: jquery, angularjs

How to load a pdf file into a div using jQuery/AngularJs

ex:

```
 $.get('/helper/test.pdf', function(data){
              $("#div1").html(data); // like to render pdf in this div
           });
```

or in angularJs

```
 $http({ method: 'GET', url: '/helper/test.pdf'}).
           success(function (data) {
               $scope.model.pdfData = data;
           }).
           error(function (data) {
               //alert(data);
           });
```

Please help me to do this

Comment: you can try using pdf.js by Mozilla using their viewer

Answer (score 2):

You can embed your PDF in iframe. There are also javascript libraries which adds some improvements.

There is SO topic about this: [How to open a PDF file in an <iframe>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12974115/to-open-pdf-file-in-iframe)

**I would consider reasons to do this again. I think it is much better to open a PDF in new window ...**