# Show PDF FILE within an asp ModalPopupExtender using C# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, webforms, modalpopupextender

I need to show a pdf file that is saved in the database and show it using an asp ModalPopupExtender

I have the fallowing code

```
 Byte[] PDF = t.ReturnPDF(NamePDF);
 Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
 Response.AddHeader("content-length", "attachment; filename=" + "NamePDF");
 Response.BinaryWrite(PDF);
 Response.Flush();
 Response.Close();
```

This works fine (it shows the pdf in the web site) however I don’t know how to show it inside of an asp ModalPopupExtender. Any suggestions or something you have done similar that can resolve my issue?

Thank you so much.

Comment: I think you cannot show the pdf inside an modalpopupextender.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use an iFrame.  However, you're going to run into browser issues as not all browsers can render PDFs inline.  See this related [answer from aam1r here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12974115/to-open-pdf-file-in-iframe)