# How to read PDF file from remote server and display with Iframe

Tags: html, iframe, file-io, ibm-bpm

`iframe src="https://127.0.0.1/test/helloworld.pdf" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe>`

I'm working on a Web Application (jsp) project where it will display the pdf content using Iframe on the web page. However, the file is situated on other remote server/file server. Is there a way for me to retrieve a file from other server and display on my Web Application via iframe?

Answer (score 0):

Doubt it. Opening PDF in your browser - is your browser settings. If my browser can't open PDF in browser - i can't see it.

Look this question on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12974315/2005367)

Comment: Thank @VBeregovoy ! I found a work around on this. Please refer to the following post :)

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution on this, we can write a java to read the PDF file from remote server and encode it to base64 string. Then, display it on the iframe src.

```
<iframe src="data:application/pdf;charset=utf-8;base64,-basepdfstringOutput-></iframe>
```