# Load PDF file into jQuery tab

Tags: jquery, pdf, itext

I have a page with jQuery tabs and I need to load a PDF file from the server into one of those tabs.  I have tried iTextSharp - but I don't want to load into an image in the page, and, as I understand it, is the only thing I can do.  I have looked at ViewerJS but that does not work as claimed. I created an iframe, loaded the entire folder at project level and called:

```
 <iframe src="./ViewerJS/#../Images/Form.pdf"></iframe>
```

I am using VS2012 on a PC that does not have IIS running, I am not allowed, so I am using the built in VS2012 one.

I have a further need to modify that PDF and post it back to the server.

Any ideas?

Comment: possible answer: [stack pdf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12974115/how-to-open-a-pdf-file-in-an-iframe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use google doc preview

Here's the code I used to embed the PDF file:

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://infolab.stanford.edu/pub/papers/google.pdf&embedded=true" style="width:600px; height:500px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

but you should replace the URL with your own address. As the document viewer works for PDF and PPT files.

Comment: this is just for  viewer to edit pdf you have use another third party library