# Could not find file 'c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\xxx.xlsx'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a MVC application that reads and uploads an Excel file and processes that file in the app, everything works fine on my local machine, but as soon as I deploy to the server,I get the following error above. I have added permissions to the IIS App Pool user to root folder, but as soon as I browse for a file through my app on my local machine, it fails with the above error. If i test it on the deployed server it works fine. Any idea what this is, I have seen a lot of posts on this, tried the suggestions but no luck. Any ideas, Please see my code below.

```
try
{
    if (file.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        var fileName = file.FileName;
        var targetFolder = Server.MapPath("/");
        string targetPath = Path.Combine(targetFolder, fileName);
        file.SaveAs(targetPath);
```

Comment: Not related to question but this page is censored in Iran because of xxx in title!

Answer (score 1):

you should use with tilde symbol(~) to point the root of the application

```
Server.MapPath("~/");
```

and it's better to use subfolder like (make sure there is that folder)

```
Server.MapPath("~/uploads/")
```

Comment: Thanks that did the trick, unfortunately only works in IE, but now in Chrome, any idea why that could be?

Comment: i think you can make it without iframe but some third party. take a look http://stackoverflow.com/a/12974315/3536006