# Embedding a external pdf link to my webpage without uploading the pdf file to server

Tags: pdf, web, plugins

I have a external link to pdf(http://du.ac.in/du/uploads/Admissions/Cut-off/2016/First/290620161st_Cut_Off_DU_1.pdf). I want to show this pdf on my webpage without uploading this file to my server. Basically i want a pdf view embeded code but with the downloadable link of pdf file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm reporting part of an [answer of another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12974315/3178454), should work

I recommend checking out [PDFObject](http://pdfobject.com/) which is a Javascript library to embed PDFs in HTML files. It handles browser compatibility pretty well and will most likely work on IE8.

In your HTML, you could set up a `div` to display the PDFs:

```
<div id="pdfRenderer"></div>
```

Then, you can have Javascript code to embed a PDF in that `div`:

```
var pdf = new PDFObject({
  url: "http://du.ac.in/du/uploads/Admissions/Cut-off/2016/First/290620161st_Cut_Off_DU_1.pdf",
  id: "pdfRendered",
  pdfOpenParams: {
    view: "FitH"
  }
}).embed("pdfRenderer");
```

Comment: there is a option for download ..but cant see the pdf