# How to display files in browser

Tags: java, html, angularjs, spring, rest

I am trying to display files (pdf, ms office files, txt) inside the browser using `<iframe>`. I am able to display txt and pdf files inside iframe, but unable to do the same for other files, open/Save dialog box appears instead of displaying them inside the iframe.
I have written the below code,

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/getPreview",method=RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getPreview(@RequestParam(value="file") String path) throws IOException{

     Path paths = Paths.get(path);
     byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(paths);
     File file = new File(path);
     String name=file.getName();
     String mime=Files.probeContentType( Paths.get(path));
     HttpHeaders headers=new HttpHeaders();
     headers.setContentType(org.springframework.http.MediaType.parseMediaType(mime));
     headers.add("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=" + name);
     headers.setCacheControl("must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
     ResponseEntity<byte[]> response = new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(data,headers, HttpStatus.OK);

     return response;

}
```

Is there any more attributes that I should add to the response header to make the requirement work?
html:`<iframe src="/getPreview?file=filePath" style="width: 400px; height: 400px;"></iframe>`

Am using angualrjs as frontend.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12974115/how-to-open-a-pdf-file-in-an-iframe maybe this would be the answer

Comment: Thanks for your reply,but I have the code which already helps me to display pdf documents.I am struggling to display other type of files.

Comment: In situations where the browser cannot display a file, it always gives the user the option of downloading it instead. This has nothing to do with if it's in an iframe or not. So it won't help to tinker with the content-disposition; what you need is to find a tool that can display MS Office files inline in the browser window.

Comment: Do u have plugin in system that can view your MS Office files over browser ?