# how to inject a dynamically generated pdf into a gwt iframe

Tags: java, pdf, servlets, iframe, gwt

I'd like to have a dynamically generated pdf to show up into an iframe, i can successfully call the servlet inside the iframe, as follows:

```
Frame frame = new Frame();
frame.setUrl( downloadUrl );
```

where "downloadUrl" is a String containing the servlet address and parameters. The problem is that at the end of the process i'm being asked if i want to download the pdf file, and the iframe remains empty.

This is the relevant part of the servlet

```
//the pdf file
byte[] outArray = null;

[...]

response.setContentType( "application/pdf" );
response.setHeader( "Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=Customer_Print.pdf" );

[...]

outArray = functionToGeneratePdfFile();

if ( outArray != null ) {
OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();
outStream.write( outArray );
outStream.flush();
}
```

Any hint?
Thanks in advance

**SOLUTION:**

Ok, i was able to get the preview inside the iframe by changing the header in the following way:

```
response.setHeader( "Content-Disposition: inline", "filename=Customer_Print.pdf" );
```

Comment: did you check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12974115/how-to-open-a-pdf-file-in-an-iframe ? probably you need to use some pdf renderer

Answer (score 1):

I think the main problem is caused by you adding the "attachment;" to the header, just remove it.