# Displaying documents in an iframe without force download?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, iframe

After browsing various solutions to display various documents in my ASP.NET website (`.doc`, `.docx`, `.pdf` etc.), I came across a simple and elegant solution that could save me a lot of trouble: display the document inside an iframe (let the browser to the work).

```
<iframe runat="server" id="foo"></iframe>
```

And then in code behind:

```
foo.Attributes["src"] = "http://example.com/docs/koby.pdf";
```

**Problem is**: The document is prompted to **download** in the browser, and not to be displayed inside it. This is hapenning because my page does not declare:

```
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="filename.pdf"
```

But then again, is it even possible to set these header attributes to an iframe?
Can someone come up with a solution or a better idea to achieve this?

Comment: If you do not have access to the original file headers I believe your only option is to rely on JavaScript and do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12974115/how-to-open-a-pdf-file-in-an-iframe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue by creating a handler:

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="GetDoc" %>

using System;
using System.Web;

public class GetDoc : IHttpHandler {

    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
        context.Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";
        context.Response.WriteFile("koby.pdf");
        context.Response.End();
    }

    public bool IsReusable {
        get {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

And setting the `<iframe>` source as:

```
foo.Attributes["src"] = "/handlers/GetDoc.ashx";
```