# Check if PDF has been loaded

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, pdf, adobe-reader

I am trying to load a PDF within an `iframe` and have to execute few events only when PDF has been loaded. (Note: By PDF getting loaded, I mean PDF contents are visible on screen not the initializing/loading progress bar of Adobe reader).
I am using the following code for now:

```
<iframe id="iframe" src="http://somedomain.com/somfilePatf/someFile.pdf">
```

I have tried `onload` event for `iframe` but it triggers as soon as page renders the `iframe` (not when `iframe` content is completely loaded).
Please help me on the same.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code/function to achieve the required options

```
<iframe id="iframe" src="http://somedomain.com/somfilePatf/someFile.pdf">  

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('iframe').onload = function() {
        functionAfterPDFLoad();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: This works as soon as the iframe is loaded (and not the PDF) and this doesnt work in IE.

Answer (score 0):

Check this answer: [How to open a PDF file in an ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12974115/how-to-open-a-pdf-file-in-an-iframe)