# Create link which opens a webpage and afterwards automatically downloads PDF document (to allow PDF download support for PWA iOS)

Tags: ios, pdf, download, safari, progressive-web-apps

When downloading a PDF in a PWA iOS app in stand alone mode, one will enter a (semi) "deadend" where the PDF is displayed, however it is not intuitive how to get back to the PWA app. See discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50721815/ios-11-standalone-web-app-link-opening-default-reversed-handling-pdf-display) - hence a "hack" is needed:

If one opens an external link in the app, the webpage is rendered nicely in the Safari in-app window also with an "OK" button in the upper left corner, which will close down the window upon pressed. Then, if within the in-app Safari browser, one clicks another link and downloads a PDF document, Safari renders the downloaded PDF nicely and keeps the "OK" button to return to the PWA app - hence the needed hack.

How can I create a link, which will first open a webpage and then, once opened, automatically next trigger a PDF download?