# PDF in iFrame getting downloaded instead of displaying

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to embed a PDF hosted on S3 for display on my website but it's getting downloaded instead of displaying it.

```
<iframe id="pdf-preview-iframe" src="https://example.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/files/1542099522240.pdf" height="100%" width="100%">
 This browser does not support PDF iFrames.                                                                    
</iframe>
```

What should i do to display it rather than downloaing it?

Comment: hope you find answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12974115/how-to-open-a-pdf-file-in-an-iframe

Comment: Your specific PDF cannot be loaded directly  - the link gives a redirect

Comment: @siddhantsankhe the one in the SO answer works but when i substitute it with my URL it downloads again :/

Comment: @mplungjan What can i do it prevent it?

Comment: Make sure the AWS does not send application/octet-stream or other mime headers