# Firefox don't display inline pdf

Tags: html, http, pdf, firefox

I want display inline a pdf into iframe. It works on Chrome but not on Firefox (latest).

HTML

```
<iframe src="/3.pdf"></iframe>
```

Server HTTP response (see content-disposition: inline)

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
vary: Origin
access-control-allow-credentials: true
content-disposition: inline; filename=3.pdf
content-type: application/pdf
date: Fri, 20 Sep 2019 10:56:36 GMT
connection: close
transfer-encoding: chunked
```

result

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12974115/how-to-open-a-pdf-file-in-an-iframe

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use embed or object tags, like this:

```
<html>
<body>
    <embed src="/3.pdf" width="500" height="375">
</body>
</html>
```