# Open pdf on input click in django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, pdf, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to open a pdf file on the input click. Please let me know if it's possible on not?

This is my form

```
<form>
     <input type="text" name="response"/>
</form>
```

I know if I want to open a file I should take `type=file` and when I click `Enter` I want to open a pdf file.

view to open a pdf file.

```
def pdf_view(request):
    try:
        return FileResponse(open('resume.pdf', 'rb'), content_type='application/pdf')
    except FileNotFoundError:
        raise Http404()
```

The above view works fine i.e when I click `/pdf/` it renders the pdf in browser but is it possible to open a file when I type `pdf` in text field and it renders a  file for me ?

Comment: I didn't try this before but this answer may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8993642/2474573

Comment: as @DenizKaplan suggested please look ContentDisposition

Comment: no, it did not help since it makes the whole page inside a pdf not my content @DenizKaplan