# .rdlc report on reportviewer not rendering the controls correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net, rendering, reportviewer, rdlc

I have this report which I am recreating from access and it is not like a regular report with tables it actually uses a lot textboxes and rectangles, I figured if I kept the width of the report to 8.1 and length to 8.9 then i set all the margins to 0.1 so it print one page so that all good but when I place a textbox on the designer to where I want it to be then I run the report and see that they are placed else where soo why is it not rendering correctly is my question? is there an easier way to create an .rdlc report in Asp.net webform that I am unaware of?

Visual Studio 2008
Report Viewer 9.0
.Net 3.5

[image]

Shows up like this in the report viewer:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your screenshots it seems that every control is smaller than its content.
Resize your textboxes or change font size; you can also modify `Padding` property to free some space. After this operation try setting `CanGrow` property to `False` for every control that don't need to grow vertically (i.e. multiline `TextBox`).

Also note that `ASP.NET` `ReportViewer` is not very good in displaying complicated reports; try export your report in PDF using the built-in functionality: if the result is better use [LocalReport.Render Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.webforms.localreport.render%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to render it directly in PDF.

Comment: Yea that exactly what i did, i made the font size smaller, added a lot more rectangles to group similar textboxes but i didnt mess around with padding and can grow, will give that a try as well. but when i render the local report directly to pdf and try to print is it gonna print the pdf or the non rendered report??

Comment: you obtain a `Byte()` containing a PDF file. if you use ASP.NET you can send this file as `Response` to client (this is a good example in C#: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2057836/how-can-i-return-a-pdf-from-a-web-request-in-asp-net)