# How to load Font Awesome icons in Internet Explorer in an svg <text> element

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, svg, browser, font-awesome

I used an svg `<text>` element like:

```
<text x="-.5" y="1"  stroke="none">&#xf0e8</text>
```

And it works perfectly, except in Internet Explorer.

I added `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />`  and it didn't work.

How can I load Font Awesome icons in svg `text` elements in Internet Explorer?

Comment: Can you post a complete example? The problem could be caused by the way Font Awesome is loaded or some other seemingly unrelated markup in your page. A related question -- [Font Awesome fonts show up as boxes on IE8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12130323/font-awesome-fonts-show-up-as-boxes-on-ie8) -- contains a variety of suggestions.

Comment: My code is just like that,I used <text> tag in my page.
i used <text x="-.5" y="1"  stroke="none">&#xf0e8</text>

Comment: @Abd The information you have provided is not enough to identify where the problem is. If I put your svg in [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/gfnLnq10/1/), it works in all browsers. So your problem lies elsewhere. Please edit your question and paste some more info in.