# Open dialogue issue with pdf generation using itext

Tags: java, spring, https, itext

I am using iText to generation in my java application.  I am able to open the pdf in web page but with the https setting the open dialogue is not working.  First it is asking to save and then open dialogue is showing whereas without https the page is directly opening in browser without any dialogue.  I am using spring and itext.
I want to open the pdf in web browser without any dialogue using https.

Answer (score 0):

It likely is not a Java issue at all, but rather a browser issue.  So, for instance, knowing which browser you are testing with would make a tremendous amount of difference here.

That being said, the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038707/cant-display-pdf-from-https-in-ie-8-on-64-bit-vista) may just be what you are looking for to get the pdf to display directly when using https.