# Target to iframe not working in IE8 on Windows 7

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, pdf, iframe

I am facing a very frustrating problem and I am right now clueless on how to solve it. I have a simple iframe inside a div in a jsp. All I am doing is submitting a form with the target as this iframe which is displaying a PDF (the form submission returns a PDF in the response) and then displaying it in a popup (Dojo dialog). Everything works fine on Chrome and even on IE8 on Windows Vista. The problem is that in IE8 on Windows 7 the popup is shown and I know that the PDF is generated but the iframe displays nothing. What can be the problem?

Comment: Note that IE uses `name` attribute to resolve target, not `id`

Comment: Yes. I know that. I do use the name attribute and it does work on IE 8 on Windows vista.

Comment: I don't believe it's OS issue, there must be something else. Can you set up demo?

Comment: Is this problem related to the use of the `target`attribute at all? Please verify that first by removing the target and letting the form response just being displayed in the same window.

Comment: yes it seems so. In a different page, if I directly open the pdf usinf iframe source, it does show it very well. Only where I use the target attribute, I have the problem

Comment: Do you have a repro URL? Which PDF plugin do you have installed? Is all of this in the Internet Zone (or is it on your Intranet?)

Comment: ok... The same code works on the browser if I access the server with http. But the moment I use SSL, I don't see the pdf in the iframe. Maybe its something to do with the response headers. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh... Finally.....I solved the problem.......  Got the idea from the following : 
[Can't display PDF from HTTPS in IE 8 (on 64-bit Vista)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038707/cant-display-pdf-from-https-in-ie-8-on-64-bit-vista)

Just set pragma, cache in the header and it works..... Phewwww....