# PDF File generated through ReportViewer not opening in Secured URL

Tags: asp.net, pdf, ssl, asp.net-mvc-5, reportviewer

I am using Reportviewer to dynamically generate the pdf after binding it with data returned from Databse. My problem is that the pdf files are opening fine while trying with internal url like- http://xxxx.xxx.com but getting issue with secured url (https://xxxxxx.xxx.com). This is happening in both IE and Chrome. Sometime the pdf gets open and sometime it does not. I am getting below pages-

[image]

I searched on net and tried the instructions given to this link- - [Can't display PDF from HTTPS in IE 8 (on 64-bit Vista)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038707/cant-display-pdf-from-https-in-ie-8-on-64-bit-vista) but didn't get anything fruitful. Can anyone please help me to understand the issue and how can it be solved.